# API's are not getting hit in deployed flask app using docker with uwsgi/nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, dockerfile, uwsgi

I am able build a docker image using this Dockerfile below.

```
FROM python:3.6
# FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6
RUN mkdir /trell-ds-framework
WORKDIR /trell-ds-framework
ADD . /trell-ds-framework/
RUN python setup.py bdist_wheel
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libatlas-base-dev gfortran nginx supervisor
RUN pip3 install uwsgi
RUN  apt-get install -y libsndfile1-dev
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -c "import nltk;nltk.download('stopwords')"
# Replace with our own nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 5000
# CMD ["python", "/trell-ds-framework/application.py"]
CMD ["uwsgi", "ds_backend.ini"]
```

Using this command to build the image
docker build -t ds_backend .

For your reference following is my `ds_backend.ini` file and `nginx.file` in same project directory as of  `Dockerfile`.

ds_backend.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
processes = 20
socket = ds_backend.sock
vacuum = true
chmod-socket = 660
die-on-term = true
socket-timeout = 300
http-timeout = 300
ignore-sigpipe=true
ignore-write-errors=true
disable-write-exception=true
```

nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass localhost:5000;
    }

}
```

Running image using this command below
`docker run -p 5001:5000 ds_backend`

And getting following output.

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 27 seconds on interpreter 0x55b062460140 pid: 1 (default app)
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 195, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 196, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 197, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 198, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 199, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 200, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 201, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 202, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid: 203, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 11 (pid: 204, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 12 (pid: 205, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 13 (pid: 206, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 14 (pid: 207, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 15 (pid: 208, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 16 (pid: 209, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 17 (pid: 210, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 18 (pid: 211, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 19 (pid: 212, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 20 (pid: 213, cores: 1)
```

But when I am trying to hit the API calls from postman using ip:port/end_point (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip:port) , API's are not getting hit and can't see the any logs in above deployment logs.

Can anybody help me out here? I am totally new to Docker deployment of flask app with nginx/uwsgi.

Any leads are highly appreciated. Thanks

PS: I have enabled both 5000 and 5001 ports in my virtual machine.

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container", so you've configured Nginx to forward to port 5000 in the Nginx container.  Even if you're not using Docker Compose, [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) is good background reading; you'll have to manually `docker network create` a network to allow connections between containers.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answer. Actually, I need to  build only one container

Comment: Is it possible to keep in only one container?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599851/bin-sh-1-cannot-create-etc-nginx-nginx-conf-directory-nonexistent-the-comma

I have tried this configuraitons to put everthing in one container but was facing some issue. Have mentioned in detail there. could you please loop into that if possible?

Comment: Best practice is one process per container.  This will also let you use a prebuilt database image, which will save you a bit of hassle.  Three containers for a database, a Flask application, and an Nginx reverse proxy should be an extremely routine configuration.